# Can a Maple Wolf convert a Blood Moon Cult player to a Werewolf?

Tags: werewolv.es

If a Maple Wolf attempts to eat a Blood Moon Cult (BMC) player who is marked by the Rite of Fenrir, do they convert them into a Werewolf for the other team, even though the Maple Wolf is a pro-village role?

Comment: I'll let someone officially answer this but in a recent game I was BMC and had 2 conversion messages on a night I was attacked by a Maple and an Omegawolf. So it would suggest it's possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An attack from a maple wolf works the same as an attack from a normal werewolf (after all, they're still a wolf, they're just trying to eat fewer innocent people these days...) so yes, it will trigger the conversion.

Any huntsman that is guarding the maple wolf's target will also trigger. After all, a huntsman is unlikely to ask a 7ft clawed monstrosity barrelling towards the person they've sworn to protect at supernatural speed if they mean any harm or not first...

Comment: If the Maples *does* convert a BMC, does it count as a meal to stop him going from hungry?